# Как сделать Flex footer с фикс высотой

Tags: css3

Хочу иметь flex footer с высотой 50px, но при установке
footer {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgba(10%, 10%, 10%, 0.9);
    color: white;
height: 50px;
}
футер просто растягивается до самого низа. Версткой занимаюсь 3 день, для меня все в новинку, не ругайте сильно. Хочется решить это именно с flex блоком.

Comment: Пробовал убрать `flex: 1`?

Comment: да, блок сразу вставал после всего контента с нужной высотой, но был отступ снизу. Читал где-то, что с flexbox самое то делать футеры, но потерял статью уже.

Comment: Посмотри, пожалуйста, ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Казалось бы, надо просто убрать `flex: 1`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: teal;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>content</div>
<div id='footer'>footer</div>
```

Comment: тут в примере вверху футер, а можешь вниз поставить?

Comment: Да, действительно, перепутать футер и хедер это ...

Comment: влепляю этот flex:1 куда могу уже)) чего-то не выходит нужный результат пока. но идею понял, спасибо))

Comment: `flex: 1` вроде нужен только когда вы хотите чтобы блок растягивался.

Comment: я могу как то код показать тут? чтобы вы проверили, а то я туплю жестко

Comment: Можете разместить код на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), а сюда вставить ссылку.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qrhyzh86/

Comment: Так, а что вам не нравится?

Comment: снизу куча места после футера, когда я убераю флекс. ну и размера в примере нет

Comment: Так у футера же и нету `flex: 1`, откуда вы его убираете? Добавьте в блок `footer { ... }` высоту: `height: 50px`.

Comment: конечно нету))) до этого был, у вас в примере предлагается flex:1 не в футер, а в контент впихнуть)) до этого у меня был flex:1 и он растягивал блок до самого низа. Но мне надо чтобы он снизу начинался, а не растягивался до туда =)

Comment: Если вы не будете убирать flex ниоткуда и просто добавите высоту к футеру, то что вам будет не нравиться?

Comment: когда я добавляю высоту, ничего не происходит, тк футер растягивается так, что у него высота около 200-300px, то есть на все свободное снизу место

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, сделать новый jsfiddle, где вы добавите высоту.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qrhyzh86/1/

Comment: Вы как-то неправильно добавляете высоту. Что насчёт этого варианта https://jsfiddle.net/qrhyzh86/2/ ?

Comment: попробуйте там растянуть по высоте, все тоже самое получается, футер словно обычный блок не прибитый к низу =(

Comment: Кажется, вам поможет добавление правила `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: только что нашел статью - https://habrahabr.ru/post/302130/ сделал как там, как раз с height 100% и там и там, толку 0, все как и раньше. от чего еще больше вопросов, чем ответов

Comment: main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
} решило проблему!!!